# fill table from dotx file before genereting pdf file with aspose

Tags: aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

I have to do the followings:

1. use a .dotx template with header, footer, table, all marked with bookmarks at placeholders that will be filled with data
2. fill with data the header and the table
3. generate a pdf file

What should be the steps to accomplish this from the coding perspective?

- To create the document with the dotx. template?
- to create grammatically a table?
- to find the bookmarks and fill them?

Please give some hints; I saw a lot of examples, but I don’t understand how to use the template and to fill it with data. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show an example of the source document.

Comment: Could you please share your input and expected output documents? I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I just added the template and the expected result here:   
   [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ES7fWS4y7HbbG5Z2CXWwF4ci6DKdaNYa/view?usp=sharing)  . Hope that is accessible, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not use the form fields in the template document. I suggest you please use LINQ Reporting to populate the template document with data that comes from database. The LINQ Reporting Engine is a part of the Aspose.Words API that enables you to build reports using an extended set of reporting features.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. It works using The LINQ Reporting Engine. Very nice, thanks!